# What is the best approch to handle env file?

Tags: node.js, webpack, environment-variables

I have `.env` file at my project root directory.

How should I handle `.env` file for dev, qa, stage and prod?

- Should include them in git repo? if not where I put them? different folder on external drive for example?
- What is the correct extensions? `.env.qa` or `.qa.env`?
- If I want to build my bundle using `webpack` to the dist folder (server side),  should I include the `env` file or manually copy it to the `dist` folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should not check-in your env files into any source control. Any of those secrets will be forever available to anyone having access to the repo until the history is rewritten to remove them.

If you use AWS services, for example, I would suggest using the [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/).

Any environment variables introduced to Webpack should not be secrets but be configuration values. Anyone who can view source can read those values. If you need to have environment-specific configurations, the Webpack [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) will replace vars like `MY_API_HOST` with their values with the following config:

```
const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    MY_API_HOST: JSON.stringify('https://my-domain.com/api/'),
    MY_API_VERSION: JSON.stringify('v2')
  })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Config module is a easy way to address the different env specific values. Read about config module at - https://www.npmjs.com/package/config. You will have a config folder in the repository with env specific files and I like this approach as the files are in the repository but very well separated.This provides a really easy way to set default values, override the environment specific values etc. It is also very convenient to use the different environment specific files by setting the appropriate node environment variable(export NODE_ENV=development or acceptance or production).